# Monetizing by lenght requests at WSO2 APIM

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

We know that is possible monetize API at , version 1.10, for requests.
Is it possible monetize for length sent contents?

Or , if not possible, can I have a report from BAM or DAS with requests length sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main objective was to monetize based request count and throttle out count. Can you explain the what do you mean by "length sent". Is it content size of the message body?

if so, APIM by default not maintain the content length. by this can be achieved by adding BAM mediator to Synapse and publishing related data to DAS/BAM.